# MVC4 Migrations from existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on an existing visual studio mvc 4 application with migrations and trying to rebuild/have it run locally. I have it mostly running with the exception of the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.QueueMember_F9E4DDD7FDA5C... to type MVC4Test.Domain.Entities.CatergoryQueueMember"

So I thought just importing the Migrations folder would suffice-- but it didn't fix anything as I'm getting the same error.

so my question: is there a way to 'clean' migrations in my new solution so that I don't keep getting the invalid cast exception??

The method that is triggering this error:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
IEnumerable<CatergoryQueue> queues = UnitOfWork.CategoryQueueRepository.Get(orderBy: o => o.OrderBy(q => q.Name), includeProperties:"QueueMembers");

IList<UserQueueModel> models = new List<UserQueueModel>();

foreach(CatergoryQueue queue in queues)
{
CatergoryQueueMember member = (CatergoryQueueMember)queue.QueueMembers.SingleOrDefault(m=>m.UserAccountID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
if(member != null)
{
UserQueueModel model = Mapper.Map<CatergoryQueue,UserQueueModel>(queue);
model.CurrentUserOpt = (currentMember.OptOut==null ? false: (bool)member.OptOut);
models.Add(model)
}
}
return View(models);
}
```

Comment: Are you pointing at a new database?

Comment: yes. it's a new database on a new server

Comment: What code is throwing that exception? Looks like some issue with QueueMember and CatergoryQueueMember so take a look at how those are defined.

Comment: I'm getting the exception from the view that renders the user queue as a table showing what catergoryqueues the user is a member of

Comment: OK, that doesn't have anything to do with migrations. You are trying to cast QueueMember into CategoryQueueMember which is throwing the exception. Try var member = queue.QueueMembers.SingleOrDefault(m=>m.UserAccountID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

Comment: @SteveGreene yea, i've tried before and met with the same error. Could it be something to do with AutoMapper or Migrations config?

Comment: Based on the error message I'm assuming it's the first line after foreach bombing? You are fetching an item from QueueMembers collection which would be of type QueueMember I assume. Unless this is a base class for CatergoryQueueMember you can't cast it. Otherwise show the QueueMembers collection class, but either substitute in my suggestion or AutoMap it instead of casting it.